# How do I make this button respond and run the listed function?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like the button I created to simply document "Heads" or "Tails" based off my function.

```
<button id="coinFlipper">Flip a Coin</button>

<script>
const coinFlip = function() {
  let randomNumber = Math.random()
  if (randomNumber < 0.5) {
    document.write("Heads")
  } else {
    document.write("Tails")
  }
}
</scipt>
```

Comment: Where do you call your function?

Comment: You need to learn the basics of JS event handling.  You may want to start here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events

Comment: And better do not use `document.write()` in GUI apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So First you need to create another element where you would display your result, than you need to create a function and assing this function on to a button with the onclick event like so -> if you want to change the text in the button just change the id of the button

```js
    const coin =()=>{
    let randomNumber = Math.random();
    if (randomNumber < 0.5) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Heads";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Tails";
  }
}
```

```html
    <button onclick="coin()" >Flip a Coin</button>
    <p id="result"></p>
```